# Get innerText from <div class> with an <a href> child

Tags: c#, html, web, webrequest

I am working with a webBrowser in C# and I need to get the text from the link. The link is just a href without a class.

its like this

```
<div class="class1" title="myfirstClass">
<a href="link.php">text I want read in C#
<span class="order-level"></span>
```

Shouldn't it be something like this?

```
        HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
        theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
        foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
        {
            if (curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString() == "class1")
            {
                HtmlElementCollection childDivs = curElement.Children.GetElementsByName("a");
                foreach (HtmlElement childElement in childDivs)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(childElement.InnerText);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't know this class, but `GetElementById` related to HTML should only retrieve 1 element with that ID, and those ID's cannot contain spaces. Nor do I see any ID's in the HTML

Comment: I am curious, what are you using a server side language to get the inner text of client side HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get the element by tag name:

```
String elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
```

And with this you should extract the value of the href:

```
var hrefLink = XElement.Parse(elem)
     .Descendants("a")
     .Select(x => x.Attribute("href").Value)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you have more then 1 "a" tag in it, you could also put in a foreach loop if that is what you want.

EDIT:

With XElement:

You can get the content including the outer node by calling `element.ToString()`.

If you want to exclude the outer tag, you can call `String.Concat(element.Nodes())`.

To get innerHTML with `HtmlAgilityPack`:

1. Install HtmlAgilityPack from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).
2. Use this code.

`HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();`

`HtmlDocument dc = web.Load("Your_Url");`

`var s = dc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@name="a"]").InnerHtml;`

I hope it helps!

Comment: XElement.Parse(elem) has to be a string. Can I just convert the HTMLElement? it throws: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Comment: You probably can just use `String` in front of `elem` instead of `HtmlElement`, my excuses.

Comment: I am new to xElement. string htmlCode = @"<a href=""/test.php?test=1;screen=main"">value<span class=""order-level""></span></a>"; var elem = XElement.Parse(htmlCode)
            .Descendants("a")
            .Select(x => x.Attribute("href").Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
            MessageBox.Show(elem);  but the mbox is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(string.Format(hrefLink));`?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll... the result is null..?

Comment: I'm sure that the link split should work, maybe I made a mistake on getting the `div` from the body, just to make sure... is it a document that you load in?

Comment: I made a string with the content (comments above). Than I parse it into XElement and do it like u do in your code. But there is no result. Can I parse a string like: string htmlCode = @"<a href=""/test.php?test=1;screen=main"">value<span class=""order-level""></span></a>"; into XElement?

Comment: you can parse it to xElement like: `XElement xmlCode = XElement.Parse(htmlCode);` if the `htmlCode` is a valid string format.

Answer (score 1):

Here I created the console app to extract the text of anchor.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "<div class=\"class1\" title=\"myfirstClass\"><a href=\"link.php\">text I want read in C#<span class=\"order-level\"></span>";
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(input);
            foreach (HtmlNode item in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div"))
            {
                var link = item.Descendants("a").First();
                var text = link.InnerText.Trim();
                Console.Write(text);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Note this is `htmlagilitypack` question so tag the question properly.

Comment: that works but when I read the input I get the normal HTML syntax. Is there a way to convert that into the right syntax? like: <div class=\"class1\"